# Sqlite3 insert item with function

Tags: python, database, sqlite, pyside2

so I have a problem adding an item to my sqlite3 database. I use a gui app that I have designed. I use a button on that gui to add an email adress to my database. Everything is perfect there. The problem is on the database side. Here is the code of the function add_email(email_adress)

```
def add_email(email_adress):
    c = conn.cursor()
    print(email_adress)
    c.execute("INSERT INTO email VALUES(?)", (email_adress,))
    conn.commit()
    print('Fini')
```

So the problem is when I click the button everything is correct. The function is called correctly. I can see in the first print the email adress that I try to add and I can see the last print that mean it should have commit correctly.

I really don't see what I do wrong some help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the table name is missing in your Query, an insert query ideally should be in format
`INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (COLUMN_NAME) VALUES (?)`

I don't know the actual name of your table but it should be changed to something like this
`c.execute("INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE_NAME (email) VALUES (?)",(email_address,))`

it could help printing the output of `conn.commit` as it may indicate the success/failure of your query.

Comment: **Unless** the table only has that one column. You can omit the column names if you supply *all* the values for a full row. But +1 anyway because I think you're almost certainly right, and the other suggestion was very good too.